# How to group query results based on date in one month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database looks like below:

```
ID |DATETIME  |T_NUMBER|SOLD|STORE_ID|
---+----------+--------+----+--------+
1  |2019-02-01|1111    |10  |STORE_1
-------------------------------------|
2  |2019-02-01|1112    |5   |STORE_1
-------------------------------------|
3  |2019-02-02|1113    |10  |STORE_1
-------------------------------------|
4  |2019-02-02|1114    |7   |STORE_1
-------------------------------------|
5  |2019-02-02|1115    |3   |STORE_1
-------------------------------------|
6  |2019-02-03|1116    |4   |STORE_1
-------------------------------------| etc.
```

And the result that what i want looks like below:

```
STORE  | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | ..... |28| 
-------+---+---+---+---+---+-------+--+
STORE_1| 2 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 0 | ..... |0 |
---------------------------------------
STORE_2| X | X | X | X | X | ..... |X |
```

A little bit explanation: Number 1, 2 ,3 ... 28 in the header means DATE in feb. 
Number 2,3,1,0 .... 0 that means Sum of transactions per DATE. The report that i want in one month. Store_2 means if any store data that i have in the future.

My T-SQL looks like below (absolutelly wrong)

```
select SUM(T_NUMBER) as 'Total' 
from store_logs
group by cast(time as date)
```

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `PIVOT` operator.

`Sum of transactions per DATE` do you mean you wanted the `COUNT` of number of transactions per day ? If this is the case change `SUM (T_NUMBER)` to `COUNT (T_NUMBER)`

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
           SELECT [STORE_ID], [DAY] = DATEPART (DAY , [DATETIME])
           FROM   store_logs
       ) AS D
       PIVOT
       (
           SUM (T_NUMBER)
           FOR DAY IN ([1], [2], [3], [4], [5], ... [31])
       ) AS P
```